# How gravity is responsible for cone-like shape of a mountain?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, everyday-life, geophysics

I searched on web and found that that the most important factor for conical (approximate) shape of a mountain is the action of rivers.

I understood it well but I again searched more on web  because what about the mountains where there are no rivers?Most of the websites suggest that it is gravity.

I think that if gravity is responsible for conical shape then everything present on this planet must be conical!Isn't it?

Comment: Mt Fuji  and Olympus Mons are volcanoes. They may be the best examples of cone shaped mountains shaped by gravity,  not  rivers.

Comment: An alluvial fan may be the best example of a conical partial mountain shaped by a river. Limestone karsr is a good example of a mountain shaped by a river that is far from cone shaped.

Comment: You might have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose